# Font resources for Qt Application

Tags: qt, fonts, pyqt5, resources

I made an application by using `Python` and `pyqt5`. I have designed the interface with `Qt Designer`. I have used the `Poppins` from Google fonts as main fonts of the program.

The problem is that when I convert the program to .exe with `pyinstaller` and open in an other computers. If the `Poppins` font does not exist on that computer the program changes the fonts. How can I import the `Poppins` font in my programs' directory so that the program works with that font with correct font in other computers?